# System.getenv couldn't retrieve the updated value in STS

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

I'm using `System.getenv()` method to retrieve the value of environment variable in STS(Spring Tool Suite) in Win7. After **updating** the value of environment variable, I always retrieve the **old value**, not the updated value, even restarting STS by clicking `restart` command on the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart STS by closing and then opening, not `restart` command.